# What is this error caused by in this cross-validation model training?

Tags: r, cross-validation, c5.0

The dataset used here has also been used in another model and it worked. Also, the C5.0 method has been used with another dataset and worked as well:

```
> fitControl<-trainControl(
+ method=cv",
+ number=10)
+ set.seed(100)
+ c50Fit<-train(class~.,data=Train,
+ method="C5.0",
Error: unexpected string constant in:
"c50Fit<-train(class~.,data=Train,
method=""
>
```

Comment: You have a quote after `cv`, but not before.  Because of this, the parenthesis closing `trainControl()` was never actually closed.

Comment: Just saw it, I was obsessed with the code behind that part and I overlooked it. ¡Many thanks!